# is it possible to pre-fill the values of a dynamic html table using php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, dynamic-data

Using the below code, i could pre-fill input elements of a form,

```
      <?PHP

       $filename = 'txt.txt';
     $str = file_get_contents($filename);
     for ($y=5; $y<=10;$y++){
     if($data[$y][0]=="PROJECT TITLE"){
    $projecttitle= $data[$y][1];}
      } ?>

          <tr>
  <th>Project Title: </th>
  <td><span class="dropt">
  <input id="projecttitle" onkeyup="ProjectTitleValidate()" value="<?php echo $projecttitle ?>" autocomplete="off" type="text" maxlength="50" name="projecttitle" title="Project Title for reference!">
  </td>
  </tr>
```

txt.txt for the above is,

```
 title: temp_12
```

but how to achieve that, for this kind of dynamic table,

```
    <script>
      function buildTable(val)
 {
 var myTable =document.getElementById("contentTable");
 var j=val;
 var r1=val;
var rows = [];
 var cells = [];

 while (myTable.hasChildNodes()) {
    myTable.removeChild(myTable.lastChild);
}


for( var i = 0; i < 1; i++ )
{
    rows[i] = myTable.insertRow(i);
    if(i%3==2)rows[i].addClass("every3rdrow");
    cells[i] = [];

    for( var x = 0; x < j ; x++ )
    {
        cells[i][x] =document.createElement((x==0)?"th":"td");
        cells[i][x].innerHTML = (x==0)?"<input id=t onchange=ty() name=t[] size=3>":"<input id=t1 onchange=ty1() name=t1[] size=3>";
        rows[rows.length - 1].appendChild(cells[i][x]);
    }
     }

      }
  buildTable(); 
 </script>

          <tr>
  <th>Number of Models:<title="Number of Models"></th>

  <td><select id="numbermodels" name="numbermodels" onmouseover="buildTable(this.value)" onchange="buildTable(this.value);buildTable4(this.value);">

  <option value="1">1</option >
  <option selected="selected" value="2">2</option >
  <option value="3">3</option >
  <option value="4">4</option >
  <option value="5">5</option >
  <option value="6">6</option >
  </select></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <th>Number of heads per model:</th>
  <td>
  <table id="contentTable" border="1" name="contentTable">
    <!-- Fill table programmatically -->
</table></td>
  </tr>
```

and txt.txt file is

```
      Vector: 23 34 43 54
```

i tried to include php inside JavaScript input elements like value=, but this does not generate the table, is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm more of a designer than programmer - so I'll offer a reply which may provoke some REAL programmers to respond.

I found the following code while I've searched for developing automation of similar functions for event calendar and gallery pages on my website. My site needs various text details inserted into date coordinated info fields - combining calendar + event info, cross-linked.

URL for SourceCode page with RSPA program:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/rspa/files/

RSPA is a component based event driven ajax enabled framework for PHP4 and PHP 5. It is a combination of plane PHP class and HTML.

Using this framework you can call server side PHP class functions from client side control events.  And in the server side function you can directly manipulate client side objects.

I Use Prototype and script.aculo.us!